# use Toolbar as an action bar doesn't inflate menu

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I'm trying to use Toolbar as an action bar, and I follow the Chris Banes guide:

https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Now following that setup I've an empty Toolbar, it seems that the getMenuInflater().inflate() doesn't work.

[image: empty Toolbar]

In my activity I've:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuhome, menu);
        [...]
```

and in onCreate():

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:allmytv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:allmytv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        allmytv:pstsIndicatorColor="#f57c1d" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was absolutely a very specific issue.
The issue was that I have a splashscreen setted with :

```
setContentView(R.layout.splashhome);
```

Toolbar was empty because I call setSupportActionBar(toolbar) when the splashscreen was active.

Moving the setSupportActionBar(toolbar) to the right place fixed it!

Comment: The only prerequisite to calling `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` should be a non-null toolbar...

Answer (score 5):

Inorder to use toolbar as actionbar you need to set the attribute windowActionBar as false.

Include the following in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
        <item name="colorPrimary">#4285F6</item>
    </style>
```

In manifest.xml under  tag use the above theme

```
android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme"
```

I have used toolbar to inflate the menu:

```
 toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
```

Comment: Unfortunately also with your proposed changes I've an empty toolbar!

Comment: you can set the title as toolbar.setTitle("ToolBar"); check if title is visible.

Comment: One does not have to specify `NoActionBar` for theme.  One can use both a Toolbar and Actionbar by calling `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
`